# xrandr --scale does not work for laptop monitor (failed request)

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, multiple-monitors, xrandr, hdpi

I have a laptop sceen (LVDS-1-1) and two external monitors: one at work (4k monitor via DisplayPort) and one at home (non-hidpi monitor via HDMI). I'm trying to create a dual-DPI setup using the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HiDPI). Scaling the external monitors work well with the --scale option to xrandr. However, since my laptop monitor is non-hidpi, I would like to scale up the UI with KDE's system setting, and then scale down the laptop monitor with xrandr, using something like `xrandr --output LVDS-1-1 --auto --scale 1.5x1.5`. But whichever scale value I provide, even if it is 1x1, xrandr gives me the following error message:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
 Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
 Minor opcode of failed request:  26 (RRSetCrtcTransform)
 Value in failed request:  0x3f
 Serial number of failed request:  55
 Current serial number in output stream:  56
```

Does `xrandr --scale` not work with laptop monitors? Or is there anything else that I can try?

For the record, I'm using an nvidia driver.